# How to convert IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IGrouping<int,string>>> to IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to partition some comma separated lines into groups of size 2 at max.
How can i convert the collection of groups to list of lists as below?
I expect the partitions to be 3 first and then 4 after grouping.

```
  List<string> chunk = new List<string>()
            {
                "a,b,c",
                "a,d,e",
                "b,c,d",
                "b,e,d",
                "b,f,g",
                "e"
            };

            var partitons = chunk.GroupBy(c => c.Split(',')[0], (key, g) => g);
            var groups = partitons.Select(x => x.Select((i, index) => new { i, index }).GroupBy(g => g.index / 2, e => e.i));
            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> parts = groups.Select(???)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I wanted

```
var parts = groups.SelectMany(x => x).Select(y => y.Select(z => z));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
partitons = groups.Select(x => x.SelectMany(y => y));
```

I get this:

[image: partitons]

Comment: what I want as output is IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> 
{
{{a,b,c},{a,d,e}}.
{{b,c,d},{b,e,d}},
{{b,f,g}},
{{e}}
}

Comment: Which is exactly what my answer gives you.

Comment: @user330612 - Except that your query doesn't split `{b,f,g}` away.

Comment: @user330612 - Oh, sorry, you want the rest of your query fixed. The title of the question is a bit off.

Comment: var parts = groups.SelectMany(x => x).Select(y => y.Select(z => z));